# ImageResizer shows wrong image

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I am using ImageResizer in my website with DiskCache plugin enabled. Randomly for some images it shows another file in the output and I should clear the cache to fix this problem while after some time I see this again for other images. Wrong image is cached just for one size of the image.

And one more thing: some times in chrome where image resizer shows wrong image this problem is solved by Ctrl+F5.

**Edit 1:**
This is my Web.config file:

```
<resizer>
    <diagnostics enableFor="AllHosts" />
    <pipeline fakeextensions=".aspx" />
    <plugins>
      <add name="Mybook.utilities.ImageResizerLocalReader" />
    </plugins>
    <diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" />
    <clientcache minutes="10080" />
</resizer>

<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

...

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="Mybook.utilities.ImageInterceptModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I still can't see diagnostic page

Comment: This question cannot be answered without additional detail; specifically, the diagnostics page output (resizer.debug) and the source code of Mybook.utilities.ImageResizerLocalReader.

Comment: How can I see diagnostic page output

Comment: some times in chrome where image resizer shows wrong image this problem is solved by Ctrl+F5

Comment: I can't see resizer.debug.ashx page

Comment: Then follow http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/diagnostics

Comment: ImageResizer is in a dll and I use this in another web project. I run web but I can't see diagnostic page. I put my web.config file relevant parts in post.

Comment: I'm using image resizer version 3.4.3.103

Comment: What error do you get when you visit  the diagnostics page? What is the exact full URL you are trying? Also, please post the code to your custom plugin or remove it for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: I got diagnostic file in code and wrote it to log file. Now in log file I have 1 issue:
DiskCache(ConfigurationError): Not working: Your NTFS Security permissions are preventing the application from writing to the disk cache
   Please give user  read and write access to directory "c:\imagecache" to correct the problem. You can access NTFS security settings by right-clicking the aformentioned folder and choosing Properties, then Security.But images are written to this directory.

Comment: But files are written to this directory and beside that I gave permission to this directory and still I got this message

Comment: I looked at source files of image resizer. I realized that this message is because of access of multi thread to a single file(Test). I wrote image resizer diagnostic file into a text file when Open method of plugin is called. Except disk cache issues there is no other issue in diagnostic. I'm really desperate. I still have some images conflicted with others(almost always with next one).Is image resizer uses multiple threads to handle requests?

Comment: Hi Hojjat, the imagecache must be within the application directory or in a virtual folder. if it's 'c:\imagecache', something is probably very wrong with your configuration. You're also installing your own Http module (and plugin!) instead of ImageResizer. 

ImageResizer is quite thread safe; the issue is probably not with ImageResizer, but with your environment and the custom code you won't show us.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your custom plugin and your custom HttpHandler.

Delete

```
<modules>
  <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="Mybook.utilities.ImageInterceptModule" />
</modules>
```

Replace with

```
<modules>
  <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
</modules>
```

And remove

```
 <add name="Mybook.utilities.ImageResizerLocalReader" />
```

Also, change `<pipeline fakeextensions=".aspx" />` to `<pipeline fakeextensions=".ashx" />`, you don't want to conflict with web pages.

Last, move this to a new, clean, standard web application in that does not map itself to the root of the `C:\` drive or do anything else crazy. Don't put web apps in the root or in a user folder. Use Inetpub or `c:\www\myapp` or something; double check your NTFS permissions are correct.

If you still experience the issue after you've eliminated environmental problems, then you should open a new question with simplified reproduction steps.

**UPDATE**

This was caused by a [global variable in the custom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410278/using-imageresizer-with-custom-query-string/32443093?noredirect=1#comment52774132_32443093).